# PHP - Calling class using variable with use keyword

Tags: php, class

I'm looking to call a function in another file using a variable for the class name. When the user logs in, I get their access level and want to use the variable received to call different menus, pages, etc. that their access level allows them access to. So for example, they could have the following access:

- Administrator
- Employee
- Public

`$access` is set to one of these variables (string value).

## 1. In my `pages.php` script, I have the following (simplified):

```
namespace Project\PageContent;

use Project\PageContent as pageContent;

class Administrator
{
    public function pageAccess()
    {
        return "Administrator access";
    }
}
class Employee
{
    public function pageAccess()
    {
        return "Employee access";
    }
}
class Public
{
    public function pageAccess()
    {
        return "Public access";
    }
}
```

## 2. Now for the way I can access it (from another page - simplified):

```
namespace Project\Main;

use Project\Main as main;

require_once('pages.php');
use Project\PageContent as pageContent;

$response = pageContent\Administrator::pageAccess();

echo $response
```

## 3. And for the way I'd like to access it (simplified) - where this obviously does not work or I wouldn't be asking the question:

```
namespace Project\Main;

use Project\Main as main;

$access = 'Administrator';

require_once('pages.php');
use Project\PageContent as pageContent;

$response = pageContent\.$access::pageAccess();

echo $response;
```

Where $access represents a string that can be used to point to the proper class (in the case above - `Administrator`)

The output of 3 should match the output of 2 and return `Administrator access`

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `$response = pageContent\{$access}::pageAccess();`?

Comment: @u_mulder I get `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting T_STRING`

Comment: If youd be using E_STRICT you would get a warning in the second version,because you access a public function as it is static

Comment: @Mihai, Thanks I've changed it in my code to reflect that. At the moment though I cannot figure out how to call a class using a variable (with the keyword use). Do you have any suggestions for me regarding that? I know I can do a switch case or an if/else with the variable and call different functions through that, but let's say down the road I decide to add more access levels, that's a lot of changes that I would need to make to my code to accommodate. I'm not saying I want this cause it's easier, but I want to use it because I'll be calling dozens of functions in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Your can't access public methods like that. You need to instantiate an object and then access that method. This is how you could call it:

```
$class = 'pageContent\\' . $otherClassName;
$obj = new $class();
$obj->pageAccess();
```

It's also worth mention that what you are doing has potential security issues with out proper validation.